# Multivariable Calc Proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $F(x,y,z)=0$ is an equation so that any variable can be solved in terms of the other two. Show that

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\cdot \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= -1.$

I understand what the question means and I am able to see how it works for a linear equation but assuming I can't set up a general linear equation (I don't think it would be sufficient enough) how would I do this proof.

Answer (score 2):

Let me write it as $$x_yy_zz_x$$
$$=x_y\dfrac{z_x}{z_y}$$ and by implicit differantation remember that $y_x=\dfrac{-G_x}{G_y}$ so we have $x_y(-y_x)=-1$.

**Note:** we regard $z=G(x,y)$